# Giving an Android device an access to only one folder

Tags: android, dropbox, privacy, upload

I have an Android camera. I want it to upload pictures to Dropbox automatically. The official Dropbox app provides that. But, I want my camera to have access ONLY to the folder that it uploads to, and not my whole Dropbox storage. So, for example, if someone takes my camera, he would not have access to anything in my Dropbox but the upload folder.

Is there an app, or some way to make a camera access and upload pics to only one folder without being able to access the rest of the Dropbox storage?

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged into your own Dropbox account you get access to all the folders. You would be trying to restrict yourself here (on a single device none the less). I suspect the only realistic mechanism would be to set up a new account for your phone, set up a folder for it to dump images and share that folder with your main Dropbox account.